# In California, who has right of way when two cars try to get to the same lane at same time?

Tags: california, traffic, vehicle

In a highway with 3 lanes, if a car driving in the left lane and another car driving in the right lane decide at same time to change lane to the middle lane, who has the right of way?

In Texas, according to Sec. 545.061, the car driving in the left lane gets priority, however I could not find anything in the California Vehicular Code that mentions this case.